# Connecting to a VPN on the Guest OS

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

I'm trying to connect my Virtual Machine (Windows 10) only to a VPN IPsec server.

I can successfully connect to that VPN (IPSec) through MacOS. I could connect Mac to the VPN and then share the connection with guest. However, my whole system would be connected to the VPN. I'm trying to connect only guest to the VPN.

When I try to connect to the VPN on the Windows VM, however, this happens:[image]

I have contacted Parallels, and they sent me these steps, which I have followed correctly (I think):

> Please perform the following steps,
>
> 1) Open Configuration Editor and create a new Network Adapter using
>   "Add" button 2) Set Bridged mode for one of them and Host-only for the
>   other.
>
> Connect to VPN from Windows, using these steps:
>
> 1) Open the Windows Control Panel -> Network Connections. 2) Click
>   'Create a new connection' link on the left-hand side of the window. 3)
>   Click Next, then choose 'Connect to the network at my workplace' from
>   the list and click Next. 4) On the Network Connection page of the
>   wizard, choose the 'Virtual Private Network connection' and click
>   Next. 5) Enter a name for the new VPN connection in the 'Company Name'
>   field and click Next. 6) In the 'Public Network' window: If you choose
>   'Automatically dial this initial connection' as default option, the
>   VPN connection will always be initiated even when the computer has not
>   been connected to Internet yet. If you choose 'Do not dial the initial
>   connection', Internet connection will be established before the new
>   VPN connection is initiated. Choose one of these options and click
>   Next. 7) Enter the name or IP address of the VPN remote access server
>   to connect to, and click Next. 8) In the "Connection Availability"
>   window you will see two options: 'My Use Only' ensures that Windows
>   makes the new connection available only to the currently logged on
>   user. 'Anyone's use' option makes the connection available to anyone.
>   Choose one of the options and click Next. 9) Click Finish. The new VPN
>   connection information has been saved.
>
> On Mac side use Internet Sharing in System Preferences to share
>   Host-guest adapter connection with Mac network interface. Note:
>   Firewall should be disabled on Windows side.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was editing registry: https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand/issues/291